# Adjust visualization plot based on columns unique value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = 

         id_easy    latitude    longitude
level_0                 
0        6454       11          3
0        6454       12          4
0        1212       11          3
0        1212       12          4 
2        2323       13          5
2        2323       14          7
2        5454       15          8
2        5454       16          9
3        25603      17          4 
3        141        18          5
```

I was trying to plot `long` and `lat` based on unique values of `level_0` and it was good:

```
for i in df.index.unique():
    my_dpi=90
    plt.figure(figsize=(600/my_dpi, 400/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

    plt.plot(df.loc[df.index != i,'longitude'],df.loc[df.index != i,'latitude'] ,
             color='silver', marker='o',linestyle='',linewidth=50, markersize=2)

    plt.plot(df.loc[i,'longitude'],df.loc[i,'latitude']  ,
              color='lightcoral',marker='o',linestyle='',linewidth=2, markersize=3)
    plt.show()
```

I got 4 plots in the len of `df`. Here is the sample. So I can see points related to `level_0` 0,1,2 and 3. (in 4 different plots. I ahve attached only one to get an idea).

[image]

## Question:

As we can see for every value of `level_0` we have 2 values of `id_easy`. What I should add to the code to get different colors of every unique `id_easy` ?
For example: in `level_0` = `0` plot `long` and `lat` of `id_easy` = `6454` in one color and for `1212` in different. Sorry in advance for complex explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,d in df.groupby(level=0):
    ax.scatter(data=d,x='latitude', y='longitude',label=i)

ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can I add it into my main code which is in the example?

Comment: replace everything from `plt.figures(...)` with my code. You can pass `figsize=...` to `plt.subplots`. And get rid of `for i in df.uniques`

Comment: It gives me color of all clusters. But my desired output is different colors of unique `id_easy` in `df[0]`